# Tornado: pass more arguments to response callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, tornado

I'm using tornado to make some async HTTP requests. as such:

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient", max_clients=10000)
HTTP_CLIENT = AsyncHTTPClient()
HTTP_CLIENT.fetch(request, handle_response)

def handle_response(response):
    """Handle response"""
```

My questions is how to pass another variable (argument) to `handle_response`? Something like this (but NOT this):

```
HTTP_CLIENT.fetch(request, handle_response, some_variable)

def handle_response(response, some_variable):
    """Handle response"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "partial":

```
from functools import partial

HTTP_CLIENT.fetch(request, partial(handle_response, some_variable))


def handle_response(some_variable, response):
    """Handle response"""
```

Note that "some_variable" is now first, before "response".